# Add header to Excel document using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm looking for a way to edit headers in Excel document online. I start looking at Graph API, but I don't see any way to do so.

Is there any documentation regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft Graph API does not not support changing the header or footer of an Excel document.

I would recommend adding your suggestion to the [UserVoice site](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: In this case, Can I use JavaScript to download Excel file to the browser, add/edit the footer and upload the file back to the cloud?

Comment: This isn't supported by office.js either. You may have to edit the ooxml directly using a 3rd party library such as https://www.aspose.com/products/cells